# LinkedList class. (ReflectiveOperationException)

Tags: java, list

I am learning Java SE and am currently at simple linked lists (page 687/1047 of Savitch's Absolute Java).

I am stuck at instantiating the `LinkList` in the main method of my demo class:

```
LinkedList1 list = new LinkedList1();
```

I tried using breakpoint and it indicates a `ReflectiveOperationException`.
This is the code:

```
public class Node1 
{  
    private String item;
    private int count;
    private Node1 link;

    public Node1()
    {
        link = null;
        item = null;
        count = 0;

    }

    public Node1(String newItem, int newCount, Node1 linkValue)
    {
        setData(newItem, newCount);
        link = linkValue;
    }

    public void setData(String newItem, int newCount)
    {
        item = newItem;
        count = newCount;
    }

    public void setLink(Node1 newLink)
    {
        link = newLink;
    }

    public String getItem()
    {
        return item;
    }

    public int getCount()
    {
        return count;
    }

    public Node1 getLink()
    {
        return link;
    }
}
```

This is the `LinkedList1` class:

```
public class LinkedList1 
{
    private Node1 head;

    public LinkedList1()
    {
        head = null;
    }

    /**
     * Adds a node at the start of the list with the specified data.
     * The added node will be the first node in the list.
     */
    public void add(String itemName, int itemCount)
    {
        head = new Node1(itemName, itemCount, head);
    }


    /**
     * Removes the head node and returns true if the list contains at least
     * one node. Returns false if the list is empty.
     */
    public boolean deleteHeadNode()
    {

        if (head != null)
        {
            head = head.getLink();
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the number of nodes in the list.
     */
    public int size()
    {
        int count = 0;
        Node1 position = head;
        while (position != null)
        {
            count++;
            head = position.getLink();
        }

        return count;
    }


    public boolean contains(String item)
    {
        return (find(item) != null);
    }


    /**
     * Finds the first node containing the target item, and returns a
     * reference to that node. If the target is not in the list, null is returned.
     */
    public Node1 find(String target)
    {
        Node1 position = head;
        String itemAtPosition;
        while(position != null)
        {
            itemAtPosition = position.getItem();
            if(itemAtPosition.equals(target))
            {
                return position;

            }
            position = position.getLink();
        }

        return null; //target was not found
    }


    public void outputList()
    {

        Node1 position = head;
        while (position != null)
        {
            System.out.println(position.getItem() + " " + position.getCount());
            position = position.getLink();
        }
    }
}
```

I think that the problem has something to do with the constructor of `Node1` having the member link of type `Node1`. I'm trying to understand how these data structures work and not just resort to using the built-in `ArrayList`(& APIs) for my projects. Can you guys have a look and point me in  the right direction. Any help would be very much appreciated.

This is my main method.

```
public class LinkedListDemo 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try
        {
            LinkedList1 list = new LinkedList1();

            list.add("apples", 1);
            list.add("bananas", 2);
            list.add("cantaloupe", 3);
            System.out.println("List has "+ list.size() + " nodes.");
            list.outputList();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the code showing where you call the constructor? I'm assuming it's in some main() method

Comment: I just executed your code and didn't get any exception, you should post your main method.

Comment: When I run my main method it simply doesn't output anything.

Comment: List has 3 entries. Cantaloupe 3 Bananas 2 Apples 1 @Jean-FrançoisSavard I already tried on eclipse on another machine

Comment: @Tabachingching Thanks for the feedback, I answered your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `size` method contains an infinite loop which explain why the outputs are never reached.

```
while (position != null)
{
    count++;
    head = position.getLink();
}
```

You are looping until position is null, but never assign anything to position and instead assign to head. Instead, you want to do

```
while (position != null)
{
    count++;
    position = position.getLink();
}
```

Now you would get the output

```
List has 3 nodes.
cantaloupe 3
bananas 2
apples 1
```